# Taking teffilin off after saying bracha

Tags: halacha, tefilin, bathroom

What should someone do, who has the urge to use the bathroom right after saying the *brachah* on putting on the tefillin? Shall he put the *tefillin shel yad* and *tefillin shel rosh* and remove them? Or can he just remove the *tefillin shel yad?*

Comment: You mean you had only put the hand tefillin on so far, but not the head tefillin?

Comment: Such a bizarrely specific situation. Why is this interesting? Why might tefillin be unique that you ask about it in particular?

Comment: This is why I make sure to relieve myself before davening. @DoubleAA

Answer (score 1):

Put shel yad, remove it, and then go to the bathroom(Shulchan Aruch 43:1). When you return, say the bracha again(shu"t Ginat Vradim OC 1:52 and Matteh Yosef 2:11, Chayei Adam 13:66, Radvaz 6:301, Shulchan Aruch Harav 30, Maharsham 3:220, Be’er Heitev 53:3, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 10:15, Shevet Halevi 9:3 and others).

Or, you could put shel yad on and cover it with your shirt before entering the bathroom for urination(Berachot 23a for source and shu"t Beit Ya'akov 72 allowing urinating with tefillin shel yad), but not for sitting. Our bathrooms have the din of a persian bathroom to allow this leniency b'sha'at ha'dchak based on the ruling of the poskim below and the Beit Ya'akov in accordance with the Gemara; in my opinion(see Har Tzvi O.C. 1:50, Chazon Ish O.C. 17:4, Igros Moshe E.H. 1:114, Yabia Omer 3:2, Teshuvos V’hanhagot 1:4, Be’er Moshe 4:3:9, Rivevot Ephraim 7:

Comment: If I remember correctly, the argument in the _gemara_ was that you may pass gasses while urinating.